# VS2008 binary 3x times slower than VS2005?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, performance, optimization, visual-studio-2005

I've just upgraded a native C++ project from VS2005-SP1 to VS2008-SP1
The first thing I tested was a very basic functionality test of the application and the first thing I noticed is that the main number-crunching algorithm performs three times slower in the VS2008 binary.
I tested again the VS2005 binary to make sure there isn't any other difference and it still performed as it did before.
Did anyone stumble into this?

Comment: Are you running optimized or debug?

Comment: running release ofcourse

Comment: Did you accidentally compile with different options?  For example, did you compile for 64-bit Windows rather than 32-bit Windows?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Strangest. Thing. Ever.

It seems that the project upgrade wizard of vs2008 simply doesn't copy the '`Optimization="2"`' property so the new project is left with no optimization in release.

The fix was to go to the properties dialog, change optimization to 1 and then back to 2.
compile again and everything works it should.

I couldn't find any official reference for this only [this obscure reference](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vcgeneral/thread/fb32033b-7bad-439b-a94c-943a17f0cbb2/) in an MSDN forum.

Comment: It's nice to know the optimizer is kicking that much butt, at least.