# Time performance in Release mode: a grotesque difference in VC++ 2008 and VC++ 2005 Express Edition

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2005, time, release

I ran the same project (with the same configuration properties) in VC++ 2008 and in VC++ 2005 Express Edition. I was surprised by the difference in time performance between them: VC++ 2008 took much more time (approximately 30% additional time) than VC++ 2005 Express Edition. Why did this happen? Is it due to Express Edition being lighter?

Answer (score 0):

Such a big difference must be because of optimization settings. If you converted your project from 2005 to 2008, take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/361730/vs2008-binary-3x-times-slower-than-vs2005). I did some tests to compare performance between VS 2003 and VS 2008, and the performance for my applications was roughly the same.

**Edit:**
I had a similar problem with 2003 to 2008 conversion. After I played with the optimization settings, trying to find a better setting, at a specific moment the performance was "back to normal". This was before I was aware of the question mentioned above. I didn't understand the reason, I still don't, but I was happy with the result... So the only advice I can give is try to change optimization settings and test again.

Comment: Hi, 

I saw the suggested question and its respective answers. I tried to change the optimization parameter to "disabled" and then back to /O2. However, time performance remains about 30% worse in VC++2008 than in VC++2005. Any additional suggestion? My VC++2008 is RTM. 

Thanks! 

Isis

Comment: See my edit above. I am afraid I don't have a better answer. What do you mean by VC++2008 RTM, that it is not the beta version? Good luck!